# Best way to extract data from xml using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to parse dozens of continuously arriving xml files, pulling out a certain data set from them.
Here is my file example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<BPS Created="2020-04-03 09:16:11">
  <Machine SerialNumber="2602" Site="" DPRelease="58.5" SoftwareRelease="4.0.3" VersionInfo="" Name="419ST39823" Type="BPS C2">
    <Expected Currency="RUB" Value="0"/>
    <ParameterSection Number="123456789" StartTime="" EndTime="" opmodename="01">
      <Operator>123456789</Operator>
      <HeadercardUnit HeaderCardID="" DepositID="123456789" denomvalue="5000" DeclaredDepositAmount="0" Currency="RUB" StartTime="2020-04-03 09:15:18" MilliSec="1" EndTime="2020-04-03 09:16:09" Rejects="YES">
        <Counter Currency="RUB" DenomID="1353" Value="500" Quality="Acc" Issue="C" Output="Stacked" Number="17"/>
        <Counter Currency="RUB" DenomID="1354" Value="1000" Quality="Acc" Issue="C" Output="Stacked" Number="31"/>
        <Counter Currency="RUB" DenomID="1338" Value="1000" Quality="Acc" Issue="B" Output="Stacked" Number="3"/>
        <Counter Currency="RUB" DenomID="1293" Value="2000" Quality="Acc" Issue="D" Output="Stacked" Number="5"/>
        <Counter Currency="RUB" DenomID="1355" Value="5000" Quality="Acc" Issue="C" Output="Stacked" Number="27"/>
        <Counter Currency="RUB" DenomID="1339" Value="5000" Quality="Acc" Issue="A" Output="Stacked" Number="5"/>
      </HeadercardUnit>
    </ParameterSection>
  </Machine>
</BPS>
```

I use XPath to extract values that i need:

```
serial = etree.XPath("/BPS/Machine/@SerialNumber")
control =  etree.XPath("/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/@Number")
oper = etree.XPath("/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/Operator/text()")
dep_num = etree.XPath("/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeadercardUnit/@DepositID")
dep_time = etree.XPath("/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeadercardUnit/@StartTime")
counters = etree.XPath("/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeadercardUnit/Counter")
```

Is this a good way to extract what i need? Or do i need use each tag as lxml Element and work with it? Probably using `find` function is slower that `xpath`

Comment: Search for "Python XML to dict"; one call should give you a handy dict of the values you need.

Comment: Generally speaking - what do you mean by a "good way"? Second, what exactly is your desired output? In particular, what's the desired output of `counters = etree.XPath("/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection/HeadercardUnit/Counter")`?

Comment: good way - i mean good performance and correct usage of functions. I've no experience with lxml. About output - i need to store data in database, so it can be dict. For Counter tag - probably it will be list of dicts. mainly i need only Value and Number attributes

Comment: To be clear -- we require questions to be about *specific problems*. Code for which no problem is known belongs on [codereview.se], but is off-topic here. (Note that there are other criteria required for acceptability on CR; before posting there, read [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) in full).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based strictly on the xml in your question, I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
serial = """[your xml above]"""

from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

content = serial.encode('utf-8')
doc = etree.XML(content)
targets = doc.xpath('/BPS/Machine/ParameterSection')
data = []
for target in targets:
   data.append(target.xpath("../@SerialNumber")[0])
   data.append(target.xpath("./@Number")[0])
   data.append(target.xpath("./Operator/text()")[0])
   data.append(target.xpath("./HeadercardUnit/@DepositID")[0])
   data.append(target.xpath("./HeadercardUnit/@StartTime")[0])
   counters = target.xpath("./HeadercardUnit/Counter")
   vals = []
   nums = []
   for counter in counters:
        vals.append(counter.xpath('./@Value')[0])
        nums.append(counter.xpath('./@Number')[0])
   data.append(vals)
   data.append(nums)
columns = ['serial', 'control' , 'oper','dep_num' , 'dep_time','Value','Number']
pd.DataFrame([data],columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
    serial  control     oper         dep_num    dep_time    Value        Number
0   2602    123456789   123456789   123456789   2020-04-03 09:15:18     [500, 1000, 1000, 2000, 5000, 5000]     [17, 31, 3, 5, 27, 5]
```

Obviously, you can play with the structure of the dataframe to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Do note the first bullet point in the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer -- questions that don't identify a specific, narrow problem (or which focus on matters of opinion or preference, as discussed in the 2nd bullet point) should generally be closed, not answered. This is definitely better code than what the OP originally had -- it fixes concrete bugs which have been asked in other questions. However, that also means that if the question were asking about one of those concrete bugs, *it would be a duplicate*. Since it's not, it's too-broad.

Comment: @JackFleeting Hi. I try to replicate this, but I get an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'`, that is reffering to `content = serial.encode('utf-8')` command. Do you have an suggestions how to solve this maybe?

Comment: @energyMax Not sure why you're getting this error. I don't get it on my end.